# How to edit Video metadata while in Binary State using Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-requests, binaryfiles

I want to download a Video file from internet using requests library and before saving that endit metadata of the video.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as file:
     file.write(r.content)
```

I just want to change the metadata to video before saving the file.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. My approach would be to first download the video and then consider using a library such as `tagpy` or `mutagen`.

I would recommend `mutagen` since I find that it has a  good documentation

See here on installation [steps](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for `mutagen`

Example code using `mutagen`

```
>>> import mutagen
>>> mutagen.File("11. The Way It Is.ogg")
{'album': [u'Always Outnumbered, Never Outgunned'],
 'title': [u'The Way It Is'], 'artist': [u'The Prodigy'],
 'tracktotal': [u'12'], 'albumartist': [u'The Prodigy'],'date': [u'2004'],
 'tracknumber': [u'11'],
>>> _.info.pprint()
u'Ogg Vorbis, 346.43 seconds, 499821 bps'
>>>
```

And then to change the title, you simply access the dictionary key and change the value of it

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC

audio = FLAC("example.flac")
audio["title"] = u"An example"
audio.pprint()
audio.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on AzyCrw4282's answer, mutagen *can* be used to do what you're looking for before saving the file.

The API docs for [mutagen.File()](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/base.html#mutagen.File) states that it's looking for a `filething`, which is "a filename or file-like object". This means that you can buffer it to an in-memory location, modify your metadata with Mutagen, then save it to disk. Please be aware that the entire binary response will be in memory, this may cause issues depending on your available system resources.

```python
from io import BytesIO

import requests
import mutagen

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    buf = BytesIO()
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
        if chunk: 
            buf.write(chunk)
    buf.seek(0)
    video = mutagen.File(buf)
    # ... do your modifications
    with open('/your/file/path.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(buf.getbuffer())
```